Could not resolve type when loading a dll file and create the instacne on .net 8 android
I have a dll file (call it MyDll.dll) and its code as following:
MyDll.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-android</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>29</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <AssemblyName>Com.Test.MyDll</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>Com.Test.MyDll</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Code of MyDll:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using static Android.App.ActivityManager;

namespace Com.Test.MyDll
{
    public class MyDll
    {
       public MyDll() {}

        public async Task MyFunc(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
            var am = (Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService) as ActivityManager)!;

            am.GetMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

            /* Do other things... */
        }
    }
}

I load the dll from external storage of Android and use Activator.CreateInstance to create the instance and try to call "MyFunc".
But the error would happen and say
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Com.Test.MyDll.:_activityManager' (2) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000013 from typeref (expected class 'Android.App.ActivityManager' in assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065') assembly:Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065 type:Android.App.ActivityManager member:(null)

And the weird thing is this is only happened on Release.
If I use Debug to build and run, it will work fine.
By the way, I haven another dll and it has the same issue.
But the difference is the package I use is System.Net.HttpClient and the TargetFramework is .netstandard2.0.
